# How to count number of words from String using shell

Tags: bash

I want to count number of words from a String using Shell.

Suppose the String is:

```
input="Count from this String"
```

Here the delimiter is space `' '` and expected output is 4.
There can also be trailing space characters in the input string like `"Count from this String "`.

If there are trailing space in the String, it should produce the same output, that is 4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
echo "$input" | wc -w
```

Use wc -w to count the number of words.

Or as per dogbane's suggestion, the echo can be got rid of as well:

```
wc -w <<< "$input"
```

If <<< is not supported by your shell you can try this variant:

```
wc -w << END_OF_INPUT
$input
END_OF_INPUT
```

Comment: That's a [Useless Use of Echo](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2012/12/useless-use-of-echo.html). Use `wc -w <<< "$input"` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tuxdude and dogbane for your replys. If I use wc -w <<< "$input" I am getting an error: **syntax error: got <&, expecting Word**. Any ideas?

Comment: Which shell are you running ?

Comment: @dogbane, true, though only if you use bash. In standard POSIX shell, `echo` is the one-line way to do this.

Comment: It's also just as easy to count words (`-w`) or characters (`-c`) of raw strings, e.g., `wc -c <<< "Count the number of characters in this string."`

Answer (score 58):

You don't need an external command like `wc` because you can do it in pure `bash` which is more efficient.

Convert the string into an array and then count the elements in the array:

```
$ input="Count from this String   "
$ words=( $input )
$ echo ${#words[@]}
4
```

Alternatively, use `set` to set positional parameters and then count them:

```
$ input="Count from this String   "
$ set -- $input
$ echo $#
4
```

Comment: The second variant has a side-effect that it would overwrite the positional parameters, like any received from the command line or parameters passed to a function (if these lines are within a function). So make sure not to rely on $1, $2, etc. after using set -- $input

Comment: @dogbane Second solution suggested by you is working fine for me but as Tuxdude pointed out, I can not replace existing parameters with new one as it will break current flow. I tried to implement first solution but unfortunately I am getting error: **syntax error: got (, expecting Newline**

Comment: Important: there are no shortcuts here; `$ words=( "Count from this String   " )` does **not** work. Bash is not [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

Comment: @MSalters that's not true here. Here, the equivalent is `words=( Count from this String    )`. With that, `echo ${#words[@]}` returns 4 as expected. If you double quote the string, you are giving a single element to the array.

Comment: In zsh, `words=( $input )` will not work, because zsh doesn't split variables into words by default. This is instead necessary: `words=( ${=input} )` -- Ref: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Roadmap.html#General-Comments-on-Syntax

Answer (score 11):

Try the following one-liner:

```
echo $(c() { echo $#; }; c $input)
```

It basically defines `c()` function and passes `$input` as the argument, then `$#` returns number of elements in the argument separated by whitespace. To change the delimiter, you may change [`IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184863/21471) (a special variable).

Comment: this is very neat :)

Answer (score 9):

To do it in pure bash avoiding side-effects, do it in a sub-shell:

```
$ input="Count from this string "
$ echo $(IFS=' '; set -f -- $input; echo $#)
4
```

It works with other separators as well:

```
$ input="dog,cat,snake,billy goat,horse"
$ echo $(IFS=,; set -f -- $input; echo $#)
5
$ echo $(IFS=' '; set -f -- $input; echo $#)
2
```

Note the use of "set -f" which disables [bash filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) in the subshell, so if the caller wants expansion it should be done beforehand (Hat Tip @mkelement0).

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest prepending `set -f;` to each `set` command (note: must be a _separate_ command) so as to (temporarily) disable pathname expansion. This ensures that input tokens such as `*` aren't accidentally expanded.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "$input" | awk '{print NF}'
```

Comment: I like the fact that with `NF-x` where x is any number, you can strip away fields that are not to be counted.

Answer (score 2):

```
function count_item() {
   return $#
}
input="one two three"
count_item $input
n=$?
echo $n
```

NOTE: function parameter passing treat space as separated
argument, therefore $# works.   $? is the return value
of the recently called function.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just chime in with a perl one-liner (avoiding 'useless use of echo'):

```
perl -lane 'print scalar(@F)' <<< $input
```

Comment: The bash echo triggers parsing which does the "counting" as a side effect, so 'useless use of echo' must be tongue in cheek :)

Comment: 'useless use of echo' was a quote used in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is efficient external command free way, like @dogbane's. But it works correctly with stars.

```
$ input="Count from *"
$ IFS=" " read -r -a words <<< "${input}"
$ echo ${#words[@]}
3
```

If `input="Count from *"` then `words=( $input )` will invoke glob expansion. So size of words array will vary depending on count of files in current directory. So we use `IFS=" " read -r -a words <<< "${input}"` instead it.

see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206